# Globally accessible helper class

Tags: object-oriented, ios, swift

I would like to get opinion if I am doing this right. I am creating a helper class that is globally accessible to my whole project. I want it to be easily called like `Facebook.loginUser()`

My code is like this:

```
class Facebook: NSObject {
  class func LoginUser() {
    println("Login user...")
  }
}
```

And on usage just call the class name and method:

```
Facebook.loginUser()
```

instead of:

```
var FB: Facebook = Facebook()
FB.loginUser()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This design pattern is known as a Singleton, and you can read more about them [here](https://thatthinginswift.com/singletons/).

It's super easy to set up a singleton in Swift, and when I use this pattern I forward all method calls to the shared instance of the class.

```
class Singleton {
    static let sharedInstance = Singleton()

    // type method (aka class method), allows for easy-access code
    class func doSomething() {
        // forward the method and any parameters to the shared instance
        sharedInstance.doSomething()
    }

    // instance method, visible through Singleton.sharedInstance
    func doSomething() {
        println("Did something.")
    }
}
```

And the usage would be like so:

```
Singleton.doSomething()
Singleton.sharedInstance.doSomething()
```

(Both call the same method, just the first one is more concise)

**Notes:**

- Apple is calling *class methods* in swift *type methods*
- I use camelCaseForMethodNames because it is a convention (instead of CapitalizingEveryWord like class names)
- People tend to have mixed opinions about Singletons (read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons), if you desire).

Comment: Read through class methods and instance method and seems like instance method is the way to go for me here. And yes I do camelCaseForMethodNames, it was a typo on my question. :)